# I want to concatenate two text fields in html and display the result in other test field

Tags: html

I have my code like this

```
First name : <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" /> <br><br>
Last name : <input type="text" name="txtLastName" /> <br><br>
Full name : <input type="text" name="txtFullName"  > <br><br>
```

if i give abc in first name text box and def in last name text box the result should be displayed as abcdef in full name text box. How to do this?

Comment: You can't ask a question like that (one that shows zero research effort) without expecting to be down-voted. Such questions dilute the quality of the site and are basically unwelcome.

Comment: @enhzflep well, you are right, but he is very new to the website, and we can cut him some slack..

Comment: @TomerW - which was precisely why I didn't down-vote without an explanation of the problem and its effects. If that makes me awful, be glad you're the better person. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @enhzflep I'm downvoted all the time because I'm a newbie, even if I put a lot of effort in trying to solve my problems *before* posting them.
Stackoverflow does *not* work like the other stack exchange communities because many programmers have a very hard time to  understand that newbies and people learning how to program have such a hard time to read the docs, and would benefit a lot from the help of the experts. I'll write a post about this soon.

Comment: @DaniPaniz - I understand to some extent the pain felt by jayadeep, yourself and others. I certainly wasn't born able to read docs and write programs. I've made many of the same mistakes and been burnt for them 20 years ago.  However, the fact remains that one can read stackoverflow anonymously and familiarize themselves with the culture and expectations, before creating an account and irritating the 'locals'. Reading docs is like exercise - you have to be able to do it yourself, I'm interested in your thoughts and would love a link to your post when you make it (or now, if done already)

Answer (score 10):

It's actually quite simple with a tiny bit of inline JavaScript using the form `oninput` attribute.

```
<form oninput="txtFullName.value = txtFirstName.value +' '+ txtLastName.value">
  First name : <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" /> <br><br>
  Last name : <input type="text" name="txtLastName" /> <br><br>
  Full name : <input type="text" name="txtFullName"  > <br><br>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RXTV7/1/

I'd also suggest using HTML5 `<output>` element instead of third input. To learn more start here: http://html5doctor.com/the-output-element/

Comment: tq for ur reply but i am getting the output directly when i am typing in the first and last name fields. is it possible to get concatenated string after pressing submit button

Comment: yea, just change `oninput` to `onsubmit` (and add `return false` if you don't actually want to submit the form).

Comment: <form onsubmit="txtFullName.value = txtFirstName.value +' '+ txtLastName.value">
  First name : <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" /> <br><br>
  Last name : <input type="text" name="txtLastName" /> <br><br>
  Full name : <input type="text" name="txtFullName"  > <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="txtFullName" value="Show Full Name" />
</form>

Comment: i m not getting the output wat is the mistake in this

Comment: `onsubmit="txtFullName.value = txtFirstName.value +' '+ txtLastName.value; return false;"`

Comment: its working but the output is showing just for a second and the form is getting refreshed what will be the possible error?

Answer (score 2):

Bind a function that generates the full name on keyup events for your inputs...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function generateFullName()
    {
        document.getElementById('fullName').innerText = 
            document.getElementById('fName').value + ' ' + 
            document.getElementById('lName').value;
    }
</script>

First Name <input type="text" id="fName" onkeyup="generateFullName()" /><br/>
Last Name <input type="text" id="lName" onkeyup="generateFullName()" /><br/>
Full Name <span id="fullName" />
```

if you want, you can have the FullName as a input too, and set it's Value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (using jQuery). it will work. But the fullname field will remain empty if the individual fields are empty

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
   $("fullName").focus(function(){
        var fullname = $("fName").val() + $("lName").val();
        $("fullName").val(fullname);
});
});
</script>

First Name <input type="text" id="fName" /><br/>
Last Name <input type="text" id="lName" /><br/>
Full Name <span id="fullName"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For manipulating HTML you'll need to use JavaScript. There are tons of good tutorials out there, for example on w3schools.com.

You may also want to check out jQuery, which makes this kind of manipulations a lot easier and more straightforward.

Comment: tq.. can't i do this only using html...

Comment: No, you need JavaScript to manipulate content on the page this way (without refreshing the page).

Comment: No, HTML is **only** markup and is incapable of actually doing anything. It's not a programming language, it's a markup language.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code for that:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function generateFullName()
   {
        document.getElementById('txtFullName').value = 
        document.getElementById('fName').value + ' ' + 
        document.getElementById('lName').value;

   }
</script>

First Name <input type="text" id="fName"  /><br/>
Last Name <input type="text" id="lName" oninput="generateFullName()" /><br/>
Full name  <input type="text" id="txtFullName" name="txtFullName"  > <br><br>
```

Also, instead of oninput event , you can opt for onblur also.